# Rally App SDK 2.0: how to get tooltip on

Tags: rally

If I have a rallygrid of PortfolioItems and I include PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate in the column configs, I get the progress bar as expected.  But when I hover over the progress bar, I don't see the tooltip with extra information that I see in Rally itself.

How do I get the tooltip to display in an app?

Sample code:

```
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: 'PortfolioItem',
                    success: function(model) {
                        this.grid = this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            model: model,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                'FormattedID',
                                'Name',
                                'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate'
                            ]
                        });
                    },
                    scope: this
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Grid Example'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a viewConfig and add the 'rallypercentdonetooltip' plugin like so:

```
success: function(model) {
    this.grid = this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        model: model,
        columnCfgs: [
            'Name',
            'FormattedID',
            'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate'
        ],
        viewConfig:{
            plugins:[
                {ptype:'rallypercentdonetooltip'}
            ]
        }
    });
```